# Update table with IF statement in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, sql-update, case

How can I do such query in PostgreSQL?

```
update table1 set column9 = 
concat(
(if (b-a from table1)>1 then b-a else 0),',',
(if (c-b from table1)>1 then c-b else 0),',',
(if (d-c from table1)>1 then d-c else 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions like this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column9 = CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN b-a > 1 then b-a ELSE 0 END, ',',
  CASE WHEN c-b > 1 then c-b ELSE 0 END, ',',
  CASE WHEN d-c > 1 then d-c ELSE 0 END
);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37c24030547dc87fd4741df591056a2f).